# Picturebox will not display image

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm writing a program that will create and load pictureboxs at run time. The problem is that they will not show up or display anything. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. i have checked and the full path for the images are correct.

```
Sub DrawScreen()
    'Call g.DrawImage to draw whatever you want in here
    Dim layers(Me.ListBox1.Items.Count) As PictureBox

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        'Create New Layer as picturebox
        layers(i) = New PictureBox
        layers(i).Parent = Me.picWatch
        layers(i).BackColor = Color.Transparent
        layers(i).Visible = True

        Select Case ListBox1.Items(i)

            Case "image"
                'Debug.Print(ListofLayers(i).Full_Path)
                layers(i).Image = Image.FromFile(ListofLayers(i).Full_Path)
                layers(i).Top = ListofLayers(i).X
                picWatch.Controls.Add(layers(i))

            Case "shape"
                'Dim g As Graphics
                'g.DrawRectangle()

            Case "text"
                Dim g As Graphics = layers(i).CreateGraphics
                g.DrawString(ListofLayers(i).Text, New Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.White, ListofLayers(i).X, ListofLayers(i).Y)

            Case Else
                Debug.Print(ListBox1.Items(i))

        End Select
    Next
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: `layers(i).Top = ListofLayers(i).X`?  X is usually left or right position.  Don't use CreateGraphics.  Use the paint event of the control.

Comment: I just noticed, what is `picWatch` and where is it?

Comment: @VisualVincent would it not have to be a container of some sort, such as a `Panel`? It seems like the most likely possibility.

Comment: @AlexM. : Of course, but I'll need to know more info about it if I am to get some clue of what could possibly be the issue. Perhaps the `.X` typo is the only thing his problem is about?

Comment: RedWiz: If it's still not working after the suggested fix, have you tried changing the back color of the picture boxes just to see if you can locate them?

Comment: picWatch is a picturebox loaded on the main form. I wanted to other picture boxes that i create to be over the top of them so they are like layers for the final image. Figured that way i can move then separately.

Comment: the problem is that i created picWatch as a picturebox during design. The other ones are used over the top of them. The problem is i see the orginal one i created but none of the others. There are no errors with the code so i'm clueless to what is wrong with making them display

Comment: Well a `PictureBox` is not designed to hold other controls. You're currently adding your new picture boxes _**inside**_ the current one. Use `Me.Controls.Add()` instead so that you add them to your form.

Comment: what about the size of your new Picturebox. Maybe their default size is 0,0

Comment: @larsTech how would i go about using the paint event to do this?

Comment: There's a link to the documentation for the `Paint` event in my answer. It contains an example for exactly what you need. -- And as F0r3v3r-A-N00b pointed out, try setting the picture boxes' `SizeMode` to `AutoSize`.

Comment: FYI the coordinates you draw the string at is relative to the control you draw it on, thus you might not want to use the same coordinates as the picture box. For instance, `(0, 0)` will be the top-left corner of the picture box you're drawing in.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The issues was the size of the box. Once i set it i was able to see them.

Answer (score 2):

You never add the picture boxes to the form. Call [**`Me.Controls.Add()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Me.Controls.Add(layers(i))
```

And as already pointed out by LarsTech:

1. You seem to have a typo here:

   ```
   layers(i).Top = ListofLayers(i).X
   ```

   `X` is the coordinate for the control's horizontal position and is the same as `.Left`.

   `Y` however is the coordinate for the control's vertical position, which is the same as `.Top`.
2. Using `CreateGraphics` is a bad idea. For starters, what you draw with it will get removed when the control is redrawn. And since you're not disposing it you'll also have memory leaks.

   Subscribe to the [**`Paint` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) for each picture box instead and do all drawing in there.

Finally, just a little note: Array declarations in VB.NET does not specify how many items there are to be in the array, but to what index the array should end at. And since arrays are zero-based, this:

```
Dim layers(Me.ListBox1.Items.Count) As PictureBox
```

...is equal to this:

```
Dim layers(0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count) As PictureBox
```

Thus the array will contain `ListBox1.Items.Count` ***plus one*** since what's inside the parentheses merely specify the lower and/or upper bound.

To create an array with the "correct" amount of items you should always specify the size ***minus one***:

```
Dim layers(Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As PictureBox
```

Comment: they are added during the select case statement

Comment: Yes, I saw that later on.

Comment: Can you use the paint event with an array? Also would i be able to select just one of the images and move it around? FOr example adjust the x or y. Assuming i could just redraw the image again with the new adjustments but i'm not sure how i would select it and move just that one without having to draw all images again.

Comment: @RedWiz666 : An array is just a list of controls. Each individual element is still a regular control, so the answer is **Yes**. Just access each control by its index like you do already.

Comment: @RedWiz666 : And yes, you would be able to move them around, but you have to write that code on your own as there is no built-in solution. There's no need redrawing anything. Moving the `PictureBox` shouldn't affect its draw  contents, and even if it does the `Paint` event is raised everytime it redraws, so you only need to subscribe to it **once**.